# Connecting to a service from outside the network

Tags: socket, networking, ip-address, port, local

I seek to run a server on the 8000 port on my machine. My computer is part of a wireless home network which is connected to the Internet by a Linksys router. In this scenario, how would a host outside this network, somewhere in the Internet, connect to my service on port 8000 ?
Because all the computers on my home network have the same ip address to a host outside. How would a request then resolve to my machine specifically?

Comment: You need to look into DMZ settings on your router (sometimes it's under gaming). Usually they can forward requests to a particular machine on your network... but this question seems off topic for this site :)

Answer (score 2):

Connect to your router -- it probably has a port forwarding option to send a  port (e.g. 8000) to a specific machine inside the network.